# Lagom -How to map the endpoint with the query parameter (which of type array) to restcall

Tags: java, query-string, lagom

```
Sample endpoint : http://localhost:9003/mas/v1/events?ids=["e1","e2","e3"]
```

I'm trying to map the query parameter to string[],
below is the service call and restcall mapping done

```
 //Mapping the query parameter to array of string
 ServiceCall<NotUsed, String> getEvents(String[] ids);

 restCall(Method.GET, "/mas/v1/events?ids", this::getEvents);
```

When i try to map the queryparameter to te String[] i get the below excpetion

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to resolve method for service call with ID RestCallId{method=GET, pathPattern='/mas/v1/events?ids'}. Ensure that the you have passed a method reference (ie, this::someMethod). Passing anything else, for example lambdas, anonymous classes or actual implementation classes, is forbidden in declaring a service descriptor.
    at com.lightbend.lagom.internal.javadsl.api.ServiceReader$$anonfun$4.apply(ServiceReader.scala:103)
    at com.lightbend.lagom.internal.javadsl.api.ServiceReader$$anonfun$4.apply(ServiceReader.scala:88)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at com.lightbend.lagom.internal.javadsl.api.ServiceReader$.resolveServiceDescriptor(ServiceReader.scala:88)
    at com.lightbend.lagom.internal.javadsl.server.JavadslServerBuilder.resolveDescriptor(JavadslServerBuilder.scala:66)
    at com.lightbend.lagom.internal.javadsl.server.JavadslServerBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(JavadslServerBuilder.scala:55)
    at com.lightbend.lagom.internal.javadsl.server.JavadslServerBuilder$$anonfun$1.apply(JavadslServerBuilder.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at com.lightbend.lagom.internal.javadsl.server.JavadslServerBuilder.resolveServices(JavadslServerBuilder.scala:49)
    at 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: [Ljava/lang/String
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.lightbend.lagom.internal.javadsl.api.MethodRefResolver$.loadClass(MethodRefResolver.scala:58)
    at com.lightbend.lagom.internal.javadsl.api.MethodRefResolver$.parseArgumentClasses$1(MethodRefResolver.scala:73)
    at com.lightbend.lagom.internal.javadsl.api.MethodRefResolver$.getArgumentClasses(MethodRefResolver.scala:95)
    at com.lightbend.lagom.internal.javadsl.api.MethodRefResolver$.resolveMethodRef(MethodRefResolver.scala:49)
    at com.lightbend.lagom.internal.javadsl.api.ServiceReader$$anonfun$4.apply(ServiceReader.scala:100)
    ... 66 more
```

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/lagom/lagom/issues/643#issuecomment-292074384)

Comment: are you missing your service implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make the `ids` parameter a `String`.

So your service call and rest call mapping will look like this.

```
 ServiceCall<NotUsed, String> getEvents(String ids);

 restCall(Method.GET, "/mas/v1/events?ids", this::getEvents);
```

So your sample endpoint will look like this.

```
Sample endpoint : http://localhost:9003/mas/v1/events?ids=e1,e2,e3
```

Then use the `String.split(regex)` method to convert the `String` `Ids` to an array in the service call implementation method.

```
@Override
public ServiceCall<NotUsed, String> getEvents(String ids) {
    String[] idsArray = ids.split(",");
    return request -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture("");
}
```